# React Test Renderer Simulating Clicks on Elements

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm testing a React component using Jest v16.0.1, react-test-renderer v15.4.0 and react-addons-test-utils v15.4.0.

The component has rendered a button:

```
<button
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-danger"
    disabled={this.state.cancelButtonDisabled}
    onClick={() => this.handleCancel()}
    ref="cancelButton"
>Cancel</button>);
```

And in my test I'm rendering the component like so:

```
const component = renderer.create(
    <MyComponent />
);

const instance = component.getInstance();
// This works but is ugly
component.toJSON().children[1].children[0].props.onClick();
// This doesn't work
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(instance.refs.cancelButton);

let tree = component.toJSON();
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

What is the recommended way to simulate a click on this button? You can traverse the JSON representation of the component but it seems like their should be a better way.

Before when I was using ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument you could pass in a reference to the component using refs to ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click

I've seen this question - [How to interact with components rendered by ReactTestRenderer / Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688661/how-to-interact-with-components-rendered-by-reacttestrenderer-jest) but I assume the API has changed as my component instance has no find() method.

Answer (score 31):

I have found a solution. Since you are using react, I assume that the onClick handler function is passed to the button as a part of the props. So you can access it through button's props.

```js
component.root.findByType('button').props.onClick();
```

Or if you have more than one button, you can do this:

```js
component.root.findByProps({ className: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-danger" }).props.onClick();
```

Comment: Works fine but if you use react-native the prop function is onPress

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's too late but `find` is an API from enzyme. The answer on the question you referred to assumed enzyme is used as mentioned on the comment.

Something like this should work.

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cancelButtonDisabled: false,
    };
  }
  handleCancel() {
    this.props.cancelAction();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-danger"
        disabled={this.state.cancelButtonDisabled}
        onClick={() => this.handleCancel()}
        ref="cancelButton"
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**MyComponent.test.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

describe('Test MyComponent', () => {
  it('should be able to click the button', () => {
    const mockFunction = jest.fn();
    const element = mount(<MyComponent cancelAction={mockFunction} />);
    element.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

without enzyme, it would look like this.

**MyComponentWithoutEnzyme.test.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

describe('Test MyComponent', () => {
  it('should be able to click the button', () => {
    const mockFunction = jest.fn();
    const element = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <MyComponent cancelAction={mockFunction} />,
    );
    const button = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(element);
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(button);
    expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Enzyme is not being used.