# React snapshot test with Jest, how can a child component calls a function from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a basic app for the sack of my training composed of tow Components App and User and a snapshot test file for the User.

The test passes for now but I want to test the methods that update the state of the parent but I don't know how to proceed, Please Help.

App component

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import data from './data/users-data.json'
import User from './components/User/User'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {users: data}
    this.clickFollowHandler = this.clickFollowHandler.bind(this)
    this.clickStarHandler = this.clickStarHandler.bind(this)
  }

  clickFollowHandler(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const updatedUsers = prevState.users.map(user => {
            if (user.id === id) {
              user.isFollowed === 'active' ? user.isFollowed = 'idle' : user.isFollowed = 'active'
            }
            return user
        })
        return {
            users: updatedUsers
        }
    })
  }

  clickStarHandler(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const updatedUsers = prevState.users.map(user => {
            if (user.id === id) {
              user.isStared === 'active' ? user.isStared = 'idle' : user.isStared = 'active'
            }
            return user
        })
        return {
            users: updatedUsers
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map(u => {
          return (
            <User 
              key={u.id}
              id={u.id}
              name={u.name}
              date={u.date}
              readingTime={u.readingTime}
              isStared={u.isStared}
              isFollowed={u.isFollowed}
              image={u.image}
              handleFollowClick={this.clickFollowHandler}
              handleStarClick={this.clickStarHandler}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

User component

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './User.module.css'
import myImage from '../../assets/images/avatar.png'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


const User = props => {

    return(
      <div className={classes.User} key={props.id}>
        <div className={classes.name}>name: {props.name}</div>
        <button onClick={() => props.handleFollowClick(props.id)}>
          {props.isFollowed === 'active' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow'}
        </button>
        <input 
          className={classes.hvrIconPop}
          checked={props.isStared === 'active' ? true : false} 
          onChange={() => props.handleStarClick(props.id)}
          type='checkbox' 
        />
        <div>date: {props.date}</div>
        <div>reading time: {props.readingTime}</div>
        <img src={myImage} alt={props.name} />
      </div>
    )

}

User.propTypes = {
  handleFollowClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleStarClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default User
```

User.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import User from './User';

const users = [{
  "id": "5d552d0058f193f2795fc814",
  "isFollowed": "active",
  "isStared": "idle",
  "image": "./assets/images/avata.png",
  "readingTime": 20,
  "name": "Walton Morton",
  "date": "Aug 9"
}];

it('renders correctly when there are no users', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<User 
    users={[]} 
    handleFollowClick={() => 'test'}
    handleStarClick={() => {}} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('renders correctly when there is one user', () => {

  const tree = renderer.create(<User users={users}
    handleFollowClick={() => 'test'}
    handleStarClick={() => {}}
     />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass your `User` component a mock function (`jest.fn()`) through its `handleFollowClick` and `handleStarClick` props, then simulate whatever is supposed to trigger the parent action (a `click` event on the `<button />` or a `change` event on the `<input />`) and test whether the corresponding mock function was called.

I personally always use Enzyme for this sort of thing, but here's how I'd assume it works using `react-test-renderer` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49504529/1941241):

```
const mockFollowClick = jest.fn();
const mockStarClick = jest.fn();

const tree = renderer.create(<User
    {...users[0]}
    handleFollowClick={mockFollowClick}
    handleStarClick={mockStarClick}
/>)

const button = tree.root.findByType('button');
const input = tree.root.findByType('input');

button.props.onClick();
expect(mockFollowClick).toHaveBeenCalled();

input.props.onChange();
expect(mockStarClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You can even check if it was called with the correct user id:

```
button.props.onClick();
expect(mockFollowClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith("5d552d0058f193f2795fc814");
```

Comment: Your first snippet works great mate, but if I add the second one it fails with this message
"Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined"
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: By doing `<User {...users[0]} />` I was hoping to send the user details from the first user, since your `User` component expects an `id` prop. If you didn't do that or pass the `id` prop directly, then `props.id` would be undefined instead of the "5d552..." id I assumed would be sent.

Comment: I tried passing <User users={...users[0]} handleFollowClick={mockFollowClick}
      handleStarClick={mockStarClick} />
but this requires some changes in the config of jest, thank you anyway, it was a pleasure learning the this test simulation.